# C++: how to reallocate array using same memory space but going down in size

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, memory-management

If I have a dynamically allocated array `char* arr = new char[100];`.

1: If I want do keep the first half of the array and deallocate the last 50 how do i do that.
So I essentially with get the same pointer but I get as if i did `char* arr = new char[50]`.

2: If I want do keep the second half of the array and deallocate the first 50 how do i do that.
So I essentially with get the original pointer plus 50 but I get as if i did `char* arr = new char[50]`.

Can I do `delete[99] arr;` and put it in a loop. I can do this by reallocating the array but I want it to be as fast as possible.

Please don't pester me about spelling and grammar I know I need to do better on that.

Comment: if fast is your primary concern, why do you want do deallocate half of the array when you still need the other half?

Comment: You cannot free part of an allocation. It's all or nothing. Best you can do is get a smaller allocation and copy what you need to the new allocation or live with half of the allocation going unused.

Comment: because I'm making a arbitrary precision integer library and if i want to bit shift more than 64 bits i need to shift Quad words(uint64_t) and if i move the pointer it is faster than re-allocating but if i move the pointer there will be forgotten memory

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc

Comment: Note: do NOT mix `realloc` and `new`. [That way lies madness.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: Just don't reallocate. Have your struct maintain its `size` its `capacity` and it's `data_ptr` and its `capacity_ptr`. If you want to "deallocate" the last 50 of your 100 bytes, you just set `size` to 50. If you want to deallocate the first 50 of your 100 bytes, you set `size` to 50 and move the `data_ptr` 50 ahead of `capacity_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the size of an allocation made via `new` at all.

If the allocation is made via `std::malloc` (or friends), you can in principle use `std::realloc` to tell the system allocator that you don't need the second half anymore, but this is not possible for the first half and I would consider it dubious whether there would be any benefit doing this at all.

Additionally `std::malloc` does not create objects before C++20 and therefore would make it quite complicated to use without undefined behavior. (In particular an array cannot be placement-newed into it realiably.)

A solution to the use case mentioned in the comments is to use two pointers instead of one in your structure: One pointer pointing to the beginning of the allocation and one pointer pointing to the beginning of the used space. You keep the first around, only to call `delete[]` on it when needed, and the other can be used to indicate the beginning of the actual data.

Similarly you would keep around two pointers to the end, one to the end of the allocation and one to the end of the used part of it (or two integers denoting the sizes of both).

Comment: thanks for clarification this is how i shall accomplish this